# R algorithm error message, what did I miss?

Tags: r

I recently started with R Studio and I am trying to get a vector sorted with a specific method.

Thank you for your help. I got it sorted out. :)

Comment: You aren't defining the function correctly. Use: `suggestion_one <- function(v) { ...`

Comment: Oh well, what a mistake! Thank you so much.

Comment: The use of complex `for' loops can generally be eliminated in R using compact functions.  If you produce a sample output, someone could probably help you do that.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean the output of the function, or the sample itself?

Comment: a sample string of outputs to understand the desired sort order.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is to define a function named `suggestion_one` like below

```
suggestion_one <- function(v) {
  n <- length(v)
  for (i in 1:(n - 1)) {
    for (j in 1:(n - 1)) {
      if (v[j] > v[j + 1]) {
        tmp <- v[j]
        v[j] <- v[j + 1]
        v[j + 1] <- tmp
      }
    }
  }
  v
}
```

Also, you should leave a `v` at the bottom as the returned value from the function

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I ran the function code to check the output:

```
suggestion_one(v)
 [1]   7   8  10  16  17  18  19  24  29  30  31  38  41  43  44  51  52  54  60  63  64  68  75  77  80  85
[27]  86  87  88  89  91  94  98  99 100
```

All you need is:

```
v2 <- sort(v) #single line of base R code
v2
 [1]   7   8  10  16  17  18  19  24  29  30  31  38  41  43  44  51  52  54  60  63  64  68  75  77  80  85
[27]  86  87  88  89  91  94  98  99 100
```